# How to install Ubuntu OS on multiple computers at the same time in a LAN

Tags: 14.04, networking, system-installation

I need to install ubuntu 0n more than 300 PC. So is there any way to install it simultNIOUSLY.

Comment: Hi There! You'll ideally need to setup a [**PXE Boot Server**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallServer) with an active DHCP to do this. The link itself is self-explained.

Comment: http://cobbler.github.io/ Cobbler is a Linux installation server that allows for rapid setup of network installation environments. It glues together and automates many associated Linux tasks so you do not have to hop between many various commands and applications when deploying new systems, and, in some cases, changing existing ones. Cobbler can help with provisioning, managing DNS and DHCP, package updates, power management, configuration management orchestration, and much more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for a managed/centralized/GUIfied way to do this, take a look at MAAS from Canonical:

https://maas.io/ .

Especially if you want to tether your deployment plan to security policies, or deploy configurations using Puppet or a similar tool.

Also check out Landscape for post-deployment updating, scripting, and health checking.

https://landscape.canonical.com/

Otherwise look to the links provided by @muru and @AzkerM in comments for more traditional PXE.

Comment: I've upvoted this answer as I believe it is the correct information. I'll just add that I prefer a more atomic approach using http://ipxe.org/ at the preboot hardware level so I can include wireless devices.